# Python Flask - how to know which version of Jinja is used?

Tags: flask, version, jinja2

As stated [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-visibility), the included template does NOT have access to `variables defined in templates`; though, with Jinja 2.1, it does.

So, my question is how to know if my installed Jinja is 2.1 version or not.

p.s.

I'm using Ubuntu EC2 machine from AWS.

[image]

Comment: In PyCharm you can see this in `File > Settings > Project: myProject > Project Interpreter`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type ["pip freeze"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html) or `pip list` to get a listing of all your python packages (including Jinja) with their version.

If you are using virtual environment, activate it first for the correct listing.

Of course pip is a prerequisite, so install "pip" if you already don't have it.

[image]

Comment: The output of `pip freeze` is meant to be written to `requirements.txt` file. `pip list` has arguably more readable format.

Comment: Thanks. I got what I need.